# How to simplify Python code by using variables to refer to lengthy object names and methods?

Tags: python

I was writing a program with objects and ran into this issue of having to constantly rewrite long object.member names within a function. e.g.

```
def function_name(object_name):
    if object_name.dict_name['key_name'] == some_value:
        object_name.dict_name['key_name'] = new_value
```

Is there a way to replace these long variable names with something shorter within the function? However, I do want the object to be modified since I'm not returning anything through this function and the object should be updated with whatever happens within this function.

Comment: From the description of your question, aren't you trying to do `object_name.dict_name['key_name'] = new_value` rather than `object_name.dict_name = new_value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
def function_name(object_name):
    d = object_name.dict_name 
    if d['key_name'] == some_value:
        d['key_name'] = new_value
```

If you also want to factor out the 'key_name', you'd need something like this:

```
def function_name(object_name):
    d = object_name.dict_name
    k = 'key_name'
    if d[k] == some_value:
        d[k] = new_value
```

You can't really make it simpler than that, because if you assign a dictionary entry to a variable, there's no way to go back and know which key was used for the assignment. So you have to store both the dictionary and the key name you are interested in.

If you do this a whole lot or don't want to keep track of dictionary and key separately, you could do something like this:

```
class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, item, key):
        self.item = item
        self.key = key
    def value(self):
        return self.item[self.key]
    def assign(self, val):
        self.item[self.key] = val

def function_name(object_name):
    item = Wrapper(object_name.dict_name, 'key_name')
    if item.value() == some_value:
        item.assign(new_value)
```

Or you could make your own subclass of dict that can emit and use refs, so you could run code like this:

```
ref = object_name.dict_name.ref('key_name')
if ref.value() == some_value
    ref.assign(new_value)
```

Or if you are often doing check-and-assign operations, you could write a function just for that:

```
def update_if_equal(d, key, old_val, new_val):
    if d[key] == old_val:
        d[key] = new_val

def function_name(object_name):
    update_if_equal(
        object_name.dict_name, 'key_name', 
        old_value, some_value
    )
```

Answer (score -4):

You can simply reassign the long object names to a variable and use that variable throughout the function. You won't need to return any values since the object itself will be modified even when you just modify this new variable because the variable is pointing to the same object.

```
fuction_name(object_name):
    var = object_name.dict_name
    if var['key_name'] == some_value:
        var['key_name'] = new_value
```

This would be equivalent to the code you have provided on the question, since *var* points to the reference of the object. However, be careful that only mutable objects (classes, dictionaries, and lists) can be referenced this way since in python they are assigned through reference.

EDIT: Sorry, I made a typo initially by assigning the new_value to var, now I have fixed it by assigning to var['key_name'].

Comment: Assigning to `var` does *not* have the same effect as assigning to `object_name.dict_name`!

Comment: do you mean `var['key_name'] = new_value`?

Comment: Both deceze and Masoud are correct. I made a typo on my initial answer, I have fixed it now. Thanks for your incisive eyes!